# How to use different types for the Users table's pk and the roles table pk in Asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to make my users table has a primary key of type Guid instead of the default string, my users entity looks like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
```

My context class looks like this

```
public class Context : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
```

But now, I have to make the Role Id of type Guid but not int like I want:

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int, UserRole>//I can't do this because UserRole is tied to User which has Guid for TKey
```

Is there a way to make the User and Role use different types for the primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, due to the extensibility of Identity you cannot do this.  Your restriction on Key types is due to the actual Identity Context, when you define this you use this signature

```
IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey>
```

It is the TKey value that drives the required primary key type for both user & role.  You can have both be int, both be string, both be Guid etc, but you cannot split them to different types.

Comment: I see, but that's really a serious limitation i my opinion, thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: I personally don't find it restrictive, but...everyone has their own use case.  I'd suggest making an Issue on GitHub if you feel strongly that this should be supported.  https://github.com/aspnet/identity/issues

Comment: This is irritating when you are trying to avoid primitives for IDs (i.e. DDD style value objects) and want to have a specific `UserId` type